# nginx proxy_pass only when rdns resolves correctly

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-dns, dns-lookup

I have a nginx server on PC_A running as a proxy for a website hosted on PC_B. The server on PC_A provides rate limiting, buffer and cache services for the website.

I would like to enable DNS lookup on PC_A and allow access to the server on PC_B only if the name resolves correctly.

I found this page https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/rdns/ that discusses such features, but I am not sure how to implement the rdns_allow or rdns_deny based on the outcome of the lookup.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: "only if the name resolves correctly".  What name?

Comment: "name" as in DNS. I would like to understand how to make the proxy act as a gate depending on whether the reverse DNS lookup process is successful or not.

Comment: How to install this rDNS module ?